# Massive increase in byte size of numpy array after np.append

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have two numpy arrays `data` and `header` generated from a series of text files. `data.shape` = `(961, 700001)` and `header.shape` = `(70001,)`. `data` is an array of floats, `header` is an array of short strings, the longest being `"R#70000"`

I want to attach `data` to the end of `header`.  To get the shapes to match I do

```
header.reshape(-1,1).transpose()        ! produces shape (1,700001)
```

Before the append, `data.nbytes = 513 MB`, `header.nbytes = 1.86 MB`, and the reshaped header has size 1.9MB.  I do my append operation:

```
data = np.append(header.reshape(-1,1).transpose(),data, axis=0)
```

At this point `data.shape` = `(962,70001)` as expected, but the size has **skyrocketed to 8,200 MB**.

What is causing the massive size increase?

Comment: Is it possible that `numpy` now converted all your values in "data" from `float` to `string` to fit them in one array, causing them to use much more memory?

Comment: Does it really make sense to add the string headers to the actual data in the first place? What do you want to achieve? It will be difficult to "work" with the data afterwards, and if it's only for e.g. writing to file, there are other ways. (Still, interesting question.)

Comment: @Aryerez, before the append `header.dtype = <U7`, and `data.dtype = float64`. After the append `data.dtype = <U32`.  Write up an answer and I'll accept